# How to render a normal and compressed version of the bibliography in one document?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, author-number

I use biblatex and biber for the bibliography and I came to the problem that I need a subset of the bibliography to be in verbose style (all authors for 5 references) and at another place in the document I need all entries as compressed as possible (about 200-300 references).

So I currently I employed `style=numeric-comp` and `maxnames=1`. The drawback is that the `maxnames` options are global only options since biblatex 1.6. (Currently I use biblatex 1.7)

So how do I render a subset in verbose style and the rest in compressed style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\makeatletter
\numdef\blx@maxbibnames{99}
\makeatother

\printbibliography

\makeatletter
\numdef\blx@maxbibnames{1}
\makeatother

\printbibliography
```

The line `\numdef\blx@maxbibnames{x}` is the command executed by the option `maxnames=x`. Thus  in the first case, it will print 99 names before switching to et al, in the second case, it will do the same but after the first one.

Comment: Awesome!, Thank you so much, this saved my live :)

Comment: you can actually use ``\defcounter{maxnames}{1}`` instead of going into the package internal mode.

Comment: @DavyLandman Have you tested it? It does not work for me with BibLaTeX 2.4.

Comment: Ah, I forgot, this is part of the `etoolbox` package. I used it in combination with `\AtEveryCite`, since by default it changes the counter locally, but prefixing it with `\global` will make it global. So the same effect should be `\global\defcounter{maxnames}{1}`.

Comment: @DavyLandman Again, I have to repeat myself. Have you tested it? `\global\defcounter{maxnames}{x}` does not work for me with BibLaTeX 2.4.

Comment: @Guido `\defcounter` on the user-level counter works with, say: `\AtBeginBibliography{\iftoggle{shortnames}{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}{}}`. Resetting the low-level counter isn't a good idea. So you should at least do it locally by wrapping `\numdef` and the corresponding `\printbibliography` in a group.

Comment: @Audrey `\AtBeginBibliography` can be only used in the preamble, so  how can you have two different bibliographies one with `et al` and the other with full list of authors? (fully agree about grouping)

Comment: @Guido Issuing `\toggletrue{shortnames}` before `\printbibliography` will give the short bibliography. You'd also need `\newtoggle{shortnames}` in the preamble, of course. It will be initialized to false.

Comment: @Audrey understood now. Thanks. Please put your comments into an answer.