# How to locally use an old package (e.g. biblatex) with TexLive?

Tags: packages

I need some old deprecated options from an old package (biblatex: local maxbibnames, version 1.5 (current 2.4)). So I do not want to mess up my texlive installation. How can I use an old package locally just for one document? I guess putting the .sty files is insufficent, as e.g. biblatex is supposed to be installed in a texmf folder and its archive contains a lot of other files.

Comment: I don't know specifically for this package, but usually, features aren't disabled if there is no other way of achieving the result. I assume you already investigated that thoroughly?

Comment: Yes, and the better solution is answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-render-a-normal-and-compressed-version-of-the-bibliography-in-one-documen, but anyway I asked myself from time to time what do I do if I must use an old package without tainting my texlive install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place the old style/class files in the same directory/folder as your document.  (You should probably create a single directory for this project.)  If there is e.g. a `biblatex.sty` in your texlive tree and one in the current directory, then LaTeX will use the one in the current directory.

With `biblatex` you must remember that the code is spread over several files, so you will need to include those too.  Have a look at the `.log` file from a latex run to see which files get loaded.

If you need to have a whole directory tree, then you can place the files in a subdirectory `subdir` and modify the search path when calling latex

```
TEXMFHOME="~/pathtosubdir/subdir:$TEXMFHOME" latex file
```

(bash syntax)

or modify your configuration via [Joseph's Wrights answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5164/15925) to how add extra searchable directories.